# Montar INSERT a partir de SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de fazer um `select` e a partir dele gerar o `insert`.
Quero partir do preposto que não conheço a estrutura da tabela, a quantidade de colunas, nada além do nome da tabela.

```
select * from cliente where nome like 'PEDRO%';
```

Viraria:

```
insert into cliente(.......) values(.......);
insert into cliente(.......) values(.......);
insert into cliente(.......) values(.......);
insert into cliente(.......) values(.......);
insert into cliente(.......) values(.......);
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso diretamente no `mysql` ?
Caso não, com o `php` é possível de alguma forma ?

Meu intuito com isso é salvar esse resultado em um arquivo `.sql` e deixar guardado na máquina.
Caso o `mysql` gere essa saída, exportarei via `php`, caso contrário, o próprio `php` deveria gerar essa saída esperada.
Mas não sei a estrutura da tabela, então não posso informar quais campos seriam preenchidos

Comment: Pedro , dá pra fazer direto no `MySQL`, confira minha resposta.

Comment: Pedro, graças a uma conversa que eu tive com o @Marconi dei uma melhorada na resposta e arrumei uns bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIÇÃO**

Após conversar com o **Marconi**, percebi que você precisa saber o tipo de dado de cada campo da sua tabela. Para fazer isso, eu usei **[mysqli_fetch_field](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)** e com os valores eu salvo em um array. Os valores desta função são retornados os números que representam o tipo de dado do campo da tabela.

Graças a **[este cidadão de bem](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php#106064)** podemos ver os valores de cada tipo nesta tabela:

```
numerics 
-------------
BIT: 16
TINYINT: 1
BOOL: 1
SMALLINT: 2
MEDIUMINT: 9
INTEGER: 3
BIGINT: 8
SERIAL: 8
FLOAT: 4
DOUBLE: 5
DECIMAL: 246
NUMERIC: 246
FIXED: 246

dates
------------
DATE: 10
DATETIME: 12
TIMESTAMP: 7
TIME: 11
YEAR: 13

strings & binary
------------
CHAR: 254
VARCHAR: 253
ENUM: 254
SET: 254
BINARY: 254
VARBINARY: 253
TINYBLOB: 252
BLOB: 252
MEDIUMBLOB: 252
TINYTEXT: 252
TEXT: 252
MEDIUMTEXT: 252
LONGTEXT: 252
```

E então criar uma função para saber se o valor que vamos concatenar necessita ou não de aspas.

```
function getTypeCampo($number){
    $numerics = array('16', '1', '2', '9', '3', '8', '4', '5', '246');
    if(in_array($number, $numerics)){
        return "numeric";
    }
    return "string";    
}
```

**Código completo:**

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo LIKE 'PEDRO%'");
// string inicial
$campos = "INSERT INTO tabela (";
$valores = "VALUES ";
$status = true;
$titposDeDados = array();
while($value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $key = 0;
    $valores .= "(";
    if($status){
        // pega o tipo de dados e monta o array 
        while($types = mysqli_fetch_field($query)){
            $titposDeDados[] = getTypeCampo($types->type);
        }
        // pega o nome dos campos da tabela e concatena em $campos
        foreach($value as $campo => $valor){
            $campos .= "`".$campo."`,";
             if($titposDeDados[$key] == 'string'){
                 $valores .= "'".$valor."',";
             } else {
                 $valores .= $valor.",";
             }
             $key++;
        }
        $status = false;
    } else {
        // concatena os valores que serão inseridos em $valores
        foreach($value as $valor){
            if($titposDeDados[$key] == 'string'){
                 $valores .= "'".$valor."',"; // se for string (varchar, text, ...)
             } else {
                 $valores .= $valor.","; // se for numerico (integer, decimal, ..)
             }
            $key++;
        }
    }
    $valores = substr($valores, 0, -1);
    $valores .= "),";
}

$insert = substr($campos, 0, -1).") ".substr($valores, 0, -1);
echo $insert; // mostra a string

function getTypeCampo($number){
    $numerics = array('16', '1', '2', '9', '3', '8', '4', '5', '246');
    if(in_array($number, $numerics)){
        return "numeric";
    }
    return "string";    
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: @PedroAugusto tranquilo! =)

Comment: Realmente tinha notado isso, mas consegui resolver isso já. De qualquer forma a resposta está mais completa.

Comment: @PedroAugusto sim... Achei interessante essa função para descobrir o tipo de dados! =) Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso eu acho que seria mais fácil com php. Você vai precisar criar um laço de repetição com os resultados. Mais ou menos assim:

```
select * from cliente where nome like 'PEDRO%';
$conexaoBanco = mysqli_query;

while($valorSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoDaQuery)){
    insert into cliente(nome, cpf, exemplo) values($valorSelect['nome'], $valorSelect['cpf'], $valorSelect['exemplo'] );
    $conexaoBanco = mysqli_query;
}
```

Bom não sei como você faz a sua conexão com o banco, coloquei apenas um exemplo ali. Qualquer coisa coloque na pergunta como você faz a conexão.